# Laravel 5 and 4 in the same domain

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

My current situation is this.

My laravel 5 is here http://example.net/cms (new project)

My laravel 4 is here http://example.net/ (old assets)

If I login in http://example.net/cms and then access the assets from http://example.net/ (L4) then my cms then will be logged out.

I'm thinking maybe this has something to do with how was the session is being saved, I think they share the same session since they are in the same domain. But that is what I want to solved since they are 2 different project I just need the assets from the L4.

Comment: i believe what you are after is you want to upgrade your old L4 to the new v5 or v5.1, check the upgrade docs http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.0

Comment: @ctf0 no not really. I want both of them to work as is. The answer below solved my problem already. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you need to change the `cookie` value in `config/session.php` (L5) and/or `app/config/session.php` (L4) to be separate.